# Codeplex MaskedTextBox - when mask is applied, databinding fails

Tags: wpftoolkit

in my application I want to make use of a maskedtextbox, replacing an ordinary textbox. I am using the maskedtextbox from CodePlex. However, I can't seem to databind to this maskedtextbox.

```
    <my:MaskedTextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" Mask="00.0000" Value="{Binding
WeightTolerance}" ValueType="{x:Type sys:Decimal}" />
```

But everytime the maskedtextbox ends up empty. I went on a search but could not find anything with maskedtextbox en databinding, so I started to wonder if it is actually at all posible.

**EDIT**

I figured out that you *can* databind with the maskedtextbox. The problem seems to be the mask. As soon as I remove that, it can bind.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the codeplex maskedtextbox is that it doesn't pad automatically. It seems like it expects that a number is always in a fixed format. So when you have e.g. 15.000 and 450.000 to go in one of your textboxes, you can only supply a mask for one of the numbers.

We ended up building a converter to do the padding.